# image flip effect using animation in android

Tags: android, animation, android-canvas

I'm currently working on an Android game

I want to create an image flip effect using animation. 
How would I do it?

Answer (score 2):

There is a good example of such [here](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html)

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but you can make it better by including a summary or relevant portions of the pages you're linking to. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
[Android Animation - Flip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364010/android-animation-flip)

or more complex:
http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html

Comment: Your answer is helpful, but you can make it better by including a summary or relevant portions of the pages you're linking to. This will also help your answer remain great even if the links you included break in the future.

Comment: Maybe you are right, but there is no reason to down vote my answer. You can comment or put your own answer. He asked a question, which is basic and quick google search. If he expect more precise answer, probably he should precise his question or comment my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to achieve this using setScaleX (for flip/reflection around the Y axis). Use setScaleY for flip/reflection around the X axis.

```
final ValueAnimator rotation = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(0, 360);
```

Then in your `onAnimationUpdate` function, set scale on X or Y using the cosine function on your range of angles.

```
view.setScaleX((float)Math.cos(Math.toRadians((Float)valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue())));
```

Hope this helps