# Android - Image animation not working as intended

Tags: android, android-animation

I have 4 clickable images surounding the center of my screen. Upon clicking one of the images I want the image to slide from it's current position to the center of the screen.

Once the image reaches the center of the screen I would like the image to flip and then have my fragment load.

How do I obtain this full sequence? I have my fragment loading but I am unsure of how to create an animation that slides my image from it's current position to the center. The layout of the page is know and is as follows.

1 2 3

4 5 6

7 8 9

where 2, 4, 6, 8 are my images that I want to slide and 5 is the position that I want them to slide to on click (then flip and show my fragment).

Thanks,
Dman

**EDIT :**

One thing I cannot get to occur is the events to play in sequence. Currently when i click the image it waits the offset that I have set on the flip_image.xml animation and then plays them all at once in the duration given to the flip_image.xml animation. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

**slide_left.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<translate 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromXDelta="0%" 
    android:toXDelta="-112%"
    android:duration="1000"/>
```

**slide_alpha.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<alpha 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:fromAlpha="0.8"
    android:toAlpha="1.0"
    android:duration="1000" />
```

**flip_image.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fromXScale="0.0"
    android:toXScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:toYScale="1.0"
    android:startOffset="1000"
    android:duration="200" />
```

**Calling Code:**

```
private void loadFragmentAnimation(final ImageView view, final int slideDirection) {
        AnimationSet animSet = new AnimationSet(true);
        animSet.addAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), slideDirection));
        animSet.addAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.slide_alpha));
        animSet.addAnimation(AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(), R.anim.flip_image));
        animSet.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {             
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {                
            }

            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                // mCallBack.categorySelected(view.getId());
            }
        });

        view.startAnimation(animSet);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [View animation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html).

1. Create an [`AnimationSet`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/AnimationSet.html) having a [`TranslateAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/TranslateAnimation.html)
   followed by a [`ScaleAnimation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/ScaleAnimation.html) to simulate a flip (you may need
   to mirror the image on the other side of the flip. Perhaps there's
   an easier way?).
2. Then set the animation to the `ImageView` using
   [`setAnimation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setAnimation%28android.view.animation.Animation%29).

I guess you should be able to specify the animation in XML too.

**Edit:**

For the flip animation, you may refer to the following links:

- [Android Animations 3D flip](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html)
- [Android Animation - Flip](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3364010/165674)

Comment: thanks a lot for this, seems to be working. One thing I cannot get to occur is the events to play in sequence. Currently when i click the image it waits the offset that I have set on one of the animations and then plays them all at once in the duration given to only the animation with the offset in it. I will supply my code above. Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: @DheerajVS I have updated my question, any help with this would be much appreciated