# android - Flip animation in imageview using multiple images

Tags: android, animation, imageview

My requirement, want to animate multiple images in single ImageView like Flipper, want to change the image in certain time interval flip in left to right, right to left, top to bottom and bottom to top.
image will flip like this [flip animation using object animator](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html)

don't want to use View flipper and object animator because want to run this feature in android 2.2 please help

Comment: Have you already tried if View Animation System could be suitable for your needs? Take a look on this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364010/android-animation-flip

Comment: thanks @Rob013 i tried this but not actual that m looking for.

Comment: Are you sure you need to animate multiple views? Perhaps you could try to just animate the Layout your views are in and probably you will get a full flipper result during the animation

Comment: as my question,want to animate multiple images in imageview like flipper in some interval