# Best practice to "flip" view in Android?

Tags: android, animation, flip

This question is about performance. My goal is to make an animation which flips view vertically. What is better, to flip the actual View inflated from XML, or make a snapshot of that view and flip bitmap image?

One of the ways to flip is described here:
http://2cupsoftech.wordpress.com/2012/09/18/3d-flip-between-two-view-or-viewgroup-on-android/

But how performant is it?? And isn't better to flip a bitmap?

Comment: use a viewflipper ...

Comment: Could you please give a bit more information? Why do you want to flip your view?

Comment: @EricTobias By flipping I mean actual 3D flip animation. Like you are holding a card, which is rotated by it's own center.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android Animation - Flip](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364010/android-animation-flip)

Comment: @Geobits no it's not duplicate, my question is about performance, but the way how to do it

Comment: @Roma Bugaian I got that but why? For example: your device should account for orientation changes by itself. What is the purpose of the rotation?

Comment: @EricTobias Rotation is just a part of technical specification document, and I should it implement it. It's used like an effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest using card flip animation as described [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/cardflip.html). It works fine. (But it depends on your `View` as well)

Snapshots are heavy in memory. Besides, you have to create the second snapshot too, if the second `Activity` isn't loaded yet.

Comment: it may work, but is has compatibility problems, and won't work on devices running API lower than 11

Comment: Which is [only about 10% of devices right now](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html), and dropping, so personally I'd still consider it. You'll find your development in general less of a headache if you can drop support for those old releases.